# Buying business product for a business associate that's abroad

Tags: united-states, banking, international-transfer

I was wondering if there's any legalities regarding the purchasing of product for a business associate that is abroad? I would buy the product and he would reimburse me the money. The products are trading card games and collectibles. This is someone I've known for many years. He is a friend, but I said business associate just because I would technically be working for him in this situation.

Comment: Is this someone you've met face to face?  There are a lot of "job opportunities" that sound just like this but are really scams, or involve criminal activity (or both).

Comment: I have added the `scams` tag to this since it reeks of a scam. How are you transferring the stuff that you buy for your "business associate" to him? Or are you just storing the stuff in your home pending his "return" from abroad? Most questions of this type usually involve "friends" or even "girlfriends" or "fiancees", not business associates (unless they are bankers from Nigeria who are executors of the estate of a deceased prince/warlord/American doing business there etc).

Comment: @DilipSarwate This is someone I've known for many years.He is a friend, but I said business associate just because I would technically be working for him in this situation. Sorry that was my bad for not clarifying.

Comment: What is "TCG" in this context?

Comment: @yoozer8 Trading Card Games

Comment: I would certainly hope that buying personal quantities of cards for a friend would not be illegal, but that is something you should check on the Law site.

Comment: So, just to be clear: you're purchasing TCGs and Collectibles for your friend, and sending them to him abroad *so that he can sell them abroad?*  You say you're "working for him in this situation" so I assume these aren't gifts for his personal use.

Comment: I'd like to echo @UnhandledExcepSean that the question of "legality" is probably better handled by Law.SE, or since the items involved are collectibles there may be specialist groups that would be more experienced. This site would be more help if you were asking things like "is this a scam?" or "is this a good idea" or "how should this be reported on my taxes?".

Comment: Well after running some thoughts past my brother he reminded me of how some things work with distributors. So the payments would have to be done through an account my friend would setup anyways.

Comment: @rockstar8577 I would have to think that would essentially be smuggling unless set up via legal means. If you don't set up an actual business and act within the law (getting a lawyer to help ensure it is proper), you will almost certainly be breaking the law. Originally, I thought you intended just to send some cards for a friend for their personal use and be reimbursed. Either way, legal questions are left to lawyers (here and there).

Answer (score 2):

**If this is legit.  Why can't he buy them himself?**

Is there a law or term of service that prevents him from buying it?

**If yes**, you are helping someone circumvent the law or the terms of service.  That would be your risk.

**If no**, it may be that the order page is just not set up for foreign orders because the seller just doesn't want to deal with international shipping.  In that case, there is no real harm done.

There is one other possibility, one of the scams out there is for foreign buyers to send money for a product and shipping to you and have you ship the product out of the funds they gave you.  Then the funds they gave you turn out to be fraudulent and the deposit is reversed. You are out a bunch of money and they get free product.

Comment: It might be more helpful to point the OP to export laws since they’re not concerned about the scam aspect.